# How to get coordinates points using fit ellipse function with their angle (opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv

Here I do findContours Methods to find all x,y coordinates of ellipse but I need both coordinates and angle values.

code

```
cv::Mat binaryImg;
cv::threshold(grayImg, binaryImg, 100, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
findContours(binaryImg, contours, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
for(size_t i = 1; i < contours.size(); i++) {
std::vector<CvPoint> points;
if(contours[i].size() >= 5) {
cv::RotatedRect Ellipse = fitEllipse(contours[i]);
majoraxis = Ellipse.size.height;
minoraxis = Ellipse.size.width;
angle = Ellipse.angle;
xcenter=Ellipse.center.x;
ycenter=Ellipse.center.y;
for(unsigned int i=0;i<contours.size();i++){
   for(unsigned int j=0;j<contours[i].size();j++)
   {
       cout << "Point(x,y)=" << contours[i][j].x << "," << contours[i][j].y << endl;

   }}
```

here my image

[image: here my image]
*The above code finds contours x,y coordinates points but I need angle from center point.And their coordinates points*

Answer (score 0):

You can use build in function ellipse2Poly()